# show div fadein after scroll **px with move right to left **px

Tags: jquery

How to fadein effect show after scroll n number of pixel.
html code is:

```
<div class="fleft process" id="fade5" style="display:none; position: ;">
    <div class="dot-circle row m0">
        <div class="icon-circle row m0">
            <img src="img/analytics.png" alt="people">
            <div class="row m0 hover-text">
                Smart Ideas<br>Steady Growth
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row m0">5. Analytics</div>
</div>
```

css code is:

```
<style>
    #fade5{
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

Jquery code:

```
<script>
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 2100) {
        $("#fade5").animate({right:100, opacity:"show"}, 5000);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, what you have done is right. What's your problem?

Comment: it's can't show fadein effect and also doesn't move

Comment: **1.** Did you load jQuery? **2.** Is your page height more than `2100px`? **3.** Any errors in console? **4.** Did you give `position: relative` or `position: absolute` to the `#fade5`?

Comment: Yes. Now it doesn't show fadein effect

Comment: I will give you a better way.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way is to use CSS transitions and opacity. Go down and back up. For demo purposes, I have given `100px` threshold.

```js
$(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 300)
      $("#fade").addClass('on');
    else
      $("#fade").removeClass('on');
  });
});
```

```css
#fade {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  background: #ccf;
  top: 10%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  width: 325px;
}

#fade.on {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
<p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
<div id="fade">
  <p>Pages you view in incognito tabs won’t stick around in your browser’s history, cookie store, or search history after you’ve closed all of your incognito tabs. Any files you download or bookmarks you create will be kept.</p>
  <p>However, you aren’t invisible. Going incognito doesn’t hide your browsing from your employer, your internet service provider, or the websites you visit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @TausifRaut Ping me here if you have any further questions. Happy to help. `:)`

Comment: Hey i have one more question. How can i set time on display opacity?

Comment: @TausifRaut `opacity: [0 - 1]`. :)

Comment: Man, allow me to go home, travel, sleep. LoL. :P Welcome. :)